# Generating sample covariance matrices in R

Tags: r, statistics

Consider the iris data set which consists of the groups Seretosa, Versicolor and Virginica. There are 50 observations for 4 variables: Sepal Length, Sepal Width, Petal Length and Petal Width. How does one calculate the sample covariance matrices for each group using R?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way...

```
lapply(split(iris[,-5],iris$Species),cov)

$setosa
             Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
Sepal.Length   0.12424898 0.099216327  0.016355102 0.010330612
Sepal.Width    0.09921633 0.143689796  0.011697959 0.009297959
Petal.Length   0.01635510 0.011697959  0.030159184 0.006069388
Petal.Width    0.01033061 0.009297959  0.006069388 0.011106122

$versicolor
             Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
Sepal.Length   0.26643265  0.08518367   0.18289796  0.05577959
Sepal.Width    0.08518367  0.09846939   0.08265306  0.04120408
Petal.Length   0.18289796  0.08265306   0.22081633  0.07310204
Petal.Width    0.05577959  0.04120408   0.07310204  0.03910612

$virginica
             Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
Sepal.Length   0.40434286  0.09376327   0.30328980  0.04909388
Sepal.Width    0.09376327  0.10400408   0.07137959  0.04762857
Petal.Length   0.30328980  0.07137959   0.30458776  0.04882449
Petal.Width    0.04909388  0.04762857   0.04882449  0.07543265
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in base R to get a named list of the covariance matrices for each group:

```
tapply(seq_along(iris[[5]]), iris[[5]], FUN = function(ind) cov(iris[ind, -5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `lapply` and a `dplyr` pipe:

```
data(iris)
library(dplyr)

l = lapply(unique(iris$Species), function(s) {
    my.matrix = iris %>% filter(Species == s) %>% select(-Species) %>% as.matrix
    return(cov(my.matrix))
})
```

The result `l` is a list of covariance matrices, in the same order of the Species as they appear in the iris data set.